# sql: join some columns

Tags: sql

I have a table called mainTable with a (string) column called "variantID". Now there are some columns(color, length, width) that depend on this variantID, meaning, that if 2 rows have the same variantID's they also have the same value in these columns.

I also have another table called variants with primary key `id`. these id's are the variantID's of the mainTable

now i want a result with one row for each variant where the id contains a certain string, containing all columns from the table variants and the mentioned columns and ideally one column with the number of rows in mainTable that have the same value in the column 'color'
Can i do this using join, group and count?

example:

maintable:

```
id | variantID | year | color | length | width
----------------------------------------------
0  | 14512374  | 2014 | black | 45     | 50
0  | 14512374  | 2015 | black | 45     | 50
0  | 98512351  | 2010 | green | 60     | 75
0  | 45687128  | 2010 | green | 60     | 75
```

variants:

```
id       | isFavorite | note
---------------------------------
14512374 | yes        | 
98512351 | no         | old
45687128 | no         | test
```

desired output (for variantId like '%123%'):

```
id       | isFavorite | note | color | length | width | count
---------------------------------
14512374 | yes        |      | black | 45     | 50    | 2
98512351 | no         | old  | green | 60     | 75    | 2
```

Comment: could u please provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: Of course you can join them, group them and count them

Comment: Specify DBMS please

Comment: edited my post.

Comment: @Ginso . . . It is still unclear.  What values go in the one row in the result set for each variant if `maintable` has different values?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this:

```
SELECT T2.id, T2.isFavorite , T2.note, min(T1.color) , min(T1.lenght), min(T1.width), 
(select count(maintable.id) FROM maintable WHERE maintable.variantID like '%123%')  FROM variants AS T2
INNER JOIN maintable ON T1.variantID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID like '%123%'
```